# Running shelveset as remote run without unshelve

Tags: tfs, teamcity

Using teamcity with TFS, is it possible to run shelveset without unshelving it first to my workspace? I found way to only run it from pending changes (therefore unshelved), but it seems weird this is not possible.

Using Visual Studio 2008 and teamcity adding 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

That feature is not currently built into TeamCity's TFS VCS plug-in.

As a work-around, you can do this using a custom build configuration parameter and a custom build step that automatically unshelves the shelveset before the build.

I created a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43793

Manual work-around:

1. Create a new build parameter:

   Name: `ShelvesetName`
   Kind: `Configuration parameter`
   Spec: `text description='The shelveset to unshelve in the format |[shelvesetname|[;username|]|]' label='Shelveset Name' validationMode='any' display='normal'`
2. Create a new build step:

   Runner Type: `Command Line`
   Step name: `Unshelve shelveset`
   Execute step: `If all previous steps finished successfully`
   Run: `Custom script`
   Custom script:
   `if "%ShelvesetName%"=="" exit /b 0`

   `"%VS2013_Path%\tf.exe" unshelve "%ShelvesetName%" "%vcsroot.vcsroot-name.tfs-root%" /recursive /noprompt /login:domain\username,password`

You may have to change `VS2013_Path` with the appropriate variable/parameter from the agent and the version of Visual Studio you're using.

You'll have to change `vcsroot-name` with the name of your vcs root, and remove the `/login` parameter or specify your own credentials.

The VCS root checkout mode must be set to `Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots)` for TeamCity to create a TFS workspace so this can work correctly.

Then finally, when you run a custom build, set the `Shelveset Name` field on the `Parameters` tab to the name of the shelveset, including the owner, like `shelveset1;domain\username`.